# Swift - View Controller called two times

Tags: xcode, swift, view, controller, segue

Hey there i got a little question,

i setup a "tableviewcontroller" and a "viewcontroller".

Next i created a segue from a prototype-cell from the "tableviewcontroller" to the "viewcontroller" and named it "detail".

Next i created a "bar-button-item" in the "tableviewcontroller" and created a segue to another viewcontroller and named the segue "edit".

Depending on what item is pressed, i want to segue to a specific view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: self)

}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "edit" {

        let recordController: SpecViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SpecViewController

        recordController.record = record

    } else if (segue.identifier == "detail") {

        var DestViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        DestViewController.parameter = "detail"

    }

}
```

My probelm is that when i press the tableviewcell, the destination view controller "DetailViewController" is called two times!!

I am not sure why this happens..

Anybody could help me with this issue??

Greetings and thanks

Comment: are you using a static tableView?

Comment: what do u mean by static? i inserted one in a main storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try that then :

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var row = indexPath.row

    if row%2 == 0
     {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("edit", sender: self)
     }
    else
    {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: self)
    }


}
```

Comment: ok but how do i check in the prepareForSegue which row was pressed ?

Comment: what do you mean  how to check? Did you do the control drag to create the segue to the new view controller and did you name it? if yes you should comment out the didSelectRowAtIndexPath code .... Than Run your app and see

Comment: ok and if the first row should forward to a different viewcontroller than the second row? how do i do this check in the prepareForSegue?

Comment: are you asking if you should two different  new view controller? yes and the check happen when you said if if (segue.identifier == "edit")

Comment: no.. i just want to set a segue-identifier in the "didSelectRowAtIndexpath"-function and than forward to the specific viewcontroller depending on the segue-identifier